# Change content of a file from the terminal

Tags: command-line

How can I change the content of a file from the terminal? I do not want to use any application like a text editor, since I want to use it for a script.

To give an example, I want to turn the file `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf` from this

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

to this

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, depending whether you want to rearrange fields on that second line or just set it to exactly what you want. Here is the simplest way to do it:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/DirectoryIndex.*/DirectoryIndex index.php/' dir.conf
```

This will change the `DirectoryIndex` line, including everything after that word, to `DirectoryIndex index.php`. The `-i.bak` saves a backup copy of the original file in `dir.conf.bak`. After running this, we have:

```
$ cat dir.conf
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>

$ cat dir.conf.bak
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I was never really good with regular expressions, but this works quite well. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
echo content > file
```

or if it's really static, have an extra copy of the file and cp it.

Comment: The problem with copying files would be that I have to manage permissions, but yes. That is a way